# Is there any way to get rid of wall grates?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm trying to build a nice, dwarfy waterfall in my main dining hall, which so far resulted in plenty of mudy Fun in my fortress.

I've designed the waterfall well to be surrounded by wall grates, mostly for esthetic and security purposes, but all in all I'm not satisfied with this layout.

The problem is that I can't destroy the wall grates. I can't q+x Remove Building. I can't d+n Remove Construction. Apparently there's no way to remove wall grates (if you don't count massive cave-ins).

Did I miss anything? Is making a cave-in the only option as of .31.25?

Comment: Okay, I see there's an actual "wall grate" building. Hunh. Investigating...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wall Grates, like any other building, can be removed by <kbd>q</kbd>uery-ing the building and pressing <kbd>x</kbd> to "remove building".

Now, you've indicated that this is not actually happening for you.

A couple suggestions: **Are you sure the cursor is over the wall grate?** If there's another building is closer, it might be latching on that one instead.

If you've successfully scheduled it for removal, **is it possible for your dwarves to reach it?** Buildings can't be constructed / deconstructed from a diagonal, even though dwarves can walk diagonally.

**Have you accidentally forbidden the wall grate's component grate?** (Check with <kbd>t</kbd> and see if it's forbidden) If a building is made out of a forbidden object, dwarves will defer to the forbiddance rather than the job to remove it (damn, lazy dwarves!).

Comment: Huh, now I can query it to remove building. I don't understand why I couldn't do that before. Of all your suggestions path-finding problems sound the most likely.